# Aws amplify upload file video - error blob

Tags: typescript, react-native, amazon-s3, blob, aws-amplify

i need to upload video to aws s3 from my application in react native

this is my method for uploading files

```
import { UploadTask } from '@aws-amplify/storage'

interface fileUpload {
    filePath: string
    userId: string
    jobId: string
    onUploadProgress: (progressEvent: { loaded: number, total: number }) => void
    onUploadError: (text: string) => void
    onUploadCompleted: () => void
  }

const uploadFile = (props: fileUpload, fileObject: Blob): UploadTask | Promise<Object> => {
    try {
      const extension = props.filePath.split('.').pop() ?? ''
      const fileName = `${props.user}_${Date.now()}.${extension}`
  
      return Storage.put(fileName, fileObject, {
        resumable: true,
        contentType: `video/${extension}`,
        progressCallback: props.onUploadProgress
      })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('errorrr', e)
      return Promise.reject(e)
    }
  }
```

as a method of taking the file

```
const getFile = async (filePath: string): Promise<Blob> => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(filePath)
      return await response.blob()
      
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('get file', e)
      return await Promise.reject(new Error())
    }
  }
```

"aws-amplify": "^4.3.37",
"react-native": "0.66.1"

But this very method of getting the Blob file gives me error

attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]: blob

How should I go about uploading files?

Comment: I upload images in my react native application using a very similar method to you and it works fine for me. Based on what you've provided, you might be retrieving an array of assets from your image library, so when you try and upload an asset to AWS you might need to do array[0]. If that's not the issue then I would need additional info on how you retrieve the files from the device to provide more help.

Comment: @man517 I am only uploading one image at a time!